# Given an object that is a String or a List of Strings, how can I get the first element (or the String)

Tags: groovy

This should be simple to answer, but I can't seem to find it. I have the following array with the following behavior:

```
println params.semester     // [1596]
println params.semester[0]  // 1

println params.semester     // [1596, 1597]
println params.semester[0]  // 1596
```

How can I get `params.semester[0]` to give be the whole value, `1596`, when there is only one element in that array?

Comment: is this grails's `params`?

Comment: @cfrick Yeah, I removed the grails tag, as it isn't anything to do with the problem at hand, which is: _"Given an object that is a String or a List of Strings, how can I get the first element (or the String)"_

Comment: @tim_yates would you mind putting this text as the question then?

Comment: In case this is `params` from grails, you can use `params.list('semester')[0]`.  It gives you always a list, even if only one value is transmitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not one element in an array, I'm guessing that's just a String

You can prove this by:

```
println params.semester.getClass().name // Will print String
```

You can do:

```
def semester = [params.semester].flatten()[0]
```

To convert a String to a list and keep a list a list

Comment: yes, I understand the following:
    params.semester.class will return java.lang.String
I need to know how to make it interpret the whole thing as the value. In other words, If there is only one value in there being interpreted as a string, how can I get the whole value. (Without doing params.semester.substring(0,4) or anything similar)

Comment: @user3845574 Added a solution

Comment: Solution does what I needed. Thanks!